# Are there any possible ways to implement typeahead or name picker capability in an XPages mobile app?

Tags: xpages

I've an XPages Web app and want to mobilize it. However, I'm encountering difficulty in finding a suitable control to let users for selecting a name from Domino Directory.

In my Web app, I use the built-in typeahead and xe:namePicker for that purpose. However, these two items would not work nicely on a mobile page. Are there any alternative solutions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard typeahead will work if you include the dojo tundra.css in your mobile app, this will be modified to be included in the future.

The name picker doesn't work as the type of control used doesn't support mobile devices well, currenty there is no in built solution, An idea that comes to mind is click a button and open a page to a dataview / repeat control that has all the names in it and a textbox to filter the list.

Comment: Yes, after including tundra.css in my mobile app, the standard typeahead works! Thanks Simon! :-)

Comment: no problem, if your happy with this can you mark it as the top answer. Thanks